# Is it possible to import Magento Products using MAGMI from the a script while specifying a single profile, but with multiple import files

Tags: magento, import, profile, magmi

Is it possible to import Magento products using MAGMI from a script by specifying a single profile, but with multiple import files?

For example, I have hundreds of brands - each with their own import file.  Can I write a simple script that will loop through the list of my import files and call magmi.php with my single profile (all of my new imports use the same profile) and use the respective brand import file as a parameter?

Instead having to create a profile for each brand...:

`php magmi.cli.php -profile=brand1importnew -mode=xcreate`

I would like to use a single profile, loop through each brand in the script and specify the brand (or an import file) as an parameter:

`php magmi.cli.php -profile=importnew -mode=xcreate -file=brand1.csv`

Does this ability exist within magmi?

Answer (score 0):

Magmi can only import one file at a time.  You can instead use a simple bash script to loop through a set of CSV files and run the Magmi CLI for each file.

1. Create a file named `import.sh`
2. In the file, paste the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   FILES=/path/to/import/*.csv
   for f in $FILES
   do
        echo "Running Magmi import with file: $f"
        php magmi.cli.php -profile=importnew -mode=xcreate -CSV:filename="${f}"
        wait
   done
   ```
3. Change the `/path/to/import/` to the directory containing your CSV import files.
4. Save `import.sh` in the same directory as `magmi.cli.php`
5. Now run the file by using the command `sh import.sh` from shell.

The file will loop through the CSV files and run the `php magmi.cli.php ...` command for each file it finds.

Comment: The -CSV parameter is what I was looking missing.  Building a script for this is what I desired.  Sorry, noob here so I am unable to vote you but!

Comment: BTW, how can I assure that it will only run one execution (import) a a time?  Will it wait to loop to the next iteration until the current import is complete?

Comment: I've added `wait` below the PHP call which should in theory wait for the process to finish before continuing.  It's untested though.

Comment: This is what I have located in the cli direcctory.  When I exeute it, I get no errors, but nothing is imported at all:                
---------
<code>     
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/home/user1/public_html/var/import/TEMP/new_products_m*.csv
for f in $FILES
do
 date
    echo "Running Magmi import with file: $f"
 FILEPATH=${FILES}${f}
    php-cli magmi.cli.php -profile=ppwd_import_new -mode=xcreate -CSV:filename=$FILEPATH
    wait
 date
 echo "Completed import of $f"
 echo ""
done
</code>
------
The profile exists and the paths are echo'ing correctly.  Also tried with 'php' and 'php-cli'.

Comment: RESOLVED:
php magmi.cli.php -profile=importnew -mode=xcreate -CSV:filename="${f}"   
instead of
php magmi.cli.php -profile=importnew -mode=xcreate -CSV:filename="${FILES}${f}"

Found the answer by looking in magmi/state/progress.txt

Hope this helps someone else!